# extracting data elements from a HTML string in Pandas

Tags: html, pandas, parsing, lxml

I gave up on initial attempts to scrape the data that I need for manually creating a CSV file.

```
0   The Kingsley School https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/warwicks...   warwickshire
1   Abberley Hall   https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/worceste...   worcestershire
2   Buttercup Primary School    https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/london-a...   london-area
3   Moorfield School    https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/yorkshir...   yorkshire-area-west
4   Avalon School   https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/merseysi...   merseyside
5   Haberdashers' Monmouth Schools  https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/wales/monmouthsh...   monmouthshire
6   Wells Cathedral School  https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/somerset...   somerset
7   Marlborough House School    https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/kent/cra...   ken
```

Then thought I'd pull in the data from the web pages using requests thus:

```
def grab_data(s):
    results = requests.get(s).content
    
    return results 
df['data'] = df['URL'].map(lambda x: grab_data(x))
```

But the results are a pigging mess. Is there a better way to parse the data that doesn't involve lots of str.replace?

```
b'\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang="en">\r\n\t<head>\r\n\t\t<meta charset="UTF-8" />\r\n\r\n\t<title>\r\n\t\tThe Kingsley School, Royal Leamington Spa - ISC\r\n\t</title>\r\n\t\t<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />\r\n\t\t<link rel="canonical" href="/schools/england/warwickshire/royal-leamington-spa/the-kingsley-school/" />\r\n\t<meta name="description" content="Information about Royal Leamington Spa, The Kingsley School" />\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\t\n\t<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\n\t<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone-no" />\n\t<!-- Google Tag Manager -->\n\t<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({\'gtm.start\':\n\t\tnew Date().getTime(),event:\'gtm.js\'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],\n\t\tj=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=\'dataLayer\'?\'&l=\'+l:\'\';j.async=true;j.src=\n\t\t\'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=\'+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);\n\t})(window,document,\'script\',\'dataLayer\',\'GTM-TCCJT7P\');</script>\n\t<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->\n\t<script src="/bundles/upper?v=C-4SuuHJ23ObmSV6TVgJvlUZTwUHbE9Mit8bUEVmwIo1"></script>\r\n \n\t<link href="/bundles/site?v=_nmQ8YRQiebaCD8eMIdpKjF42e4TM9br-6hkul2424o1" rel="stylesheet"/>\r\n \n\t<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon/isc/apple-touch-icon.png">\r\n<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon/isc/favicon-32x32.png">\r\n<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon/isc/favicon-16x16.png">\r\n<link rel="manifest" href="/favicon/isc/site.webmanifest">\r\n<link rel="mask-icon" href="/favicon/isc/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">\r\n<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffc40d">\r\n<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/favicon/isc/browserconfig.xml">\r\n<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">\n\t\n\t<script>\n\t\tvar aId = 0; // mz values\n\t\tvar sId = 0;\n\t\tvar mID = 0;\n\n\n\t</script>\n\t<script src=\'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js\'></script>\n\t<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">\n\t\r\n\r\n\t\t<script type="application/ld+json">\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n  "@context": "https://schema.org",\r\n  "@type": "School",\r\n  "name": "The Kingsley School",\r\n  "url": "https://www.thekingsleyschool.co.uk/",\r\n  "description": "Kingsley provides a friendly, supportive family environment where individuals are encouraged to enjoy learning, and to aim for and achieve excellence. Our principal aim is to enable all our pupils to fulfil their potential wherever it may lie, through our wide range of subjects, lively extra-curricular activities, small classes and highly effective pastoral care.\\r\\n",\r\n  "address": {\r\n    "@type": "PostalAddress",\r\n    "addressCountry": "England",\r\n    "addressLocality": "Royal Leamington Spa",\r\n    "streetAddress": "Beauchamp Avenue",\r\n    "postalCode": "CV32 5RD",\r\n    "telephone": "+44 (0)1926 425127"\r\n  },\r\n  "geo": {\r\n    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",\r\n    "latitude": 52.2942769,\r\n    "longitude": -1.5379113\r\n  },\r\n  "email": "schooloffice@kingsleyschool.co.uk"\r\n}\r\n\t\t</script>\r\n\t\n\r\n\t</head>\r\n\t<body>\r\n\t<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->\r\n\t<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TCCJT7P"\r\n\t                  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>\r\n\t<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->\r\n\t\n<script>\n\t(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {\n\t\ti[\'GoogleAnalyticsObject\'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {\n\t\t\t(i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)\n\t\t}, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),\n\t\t\tm = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)\n\t})(window, document, \'script\', \'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js\', \'ga\');\n\tga(\'create\', \'UA-30159752-1\', \'auto\');\n\tga(\'send\', \'pageview\');\n</script>\n\n<script type="text/javascript"
```

I want to try a method in lxml in python and wanted to pull out values from HTML.

For instance, a lot of the HTML is messy. How do I search for a particular phrase in a document when all I've got is the HTML and no real structure that I can find?

Comment: What is the URL and what information do you need to get? Can you use `beautifulsoup`?

Comment: It is a list of schools. In this format: https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/wales/monmouthshire/monmouth/haberdashers-monmouth-schools/  I'd like to use lxml but ideally need most of the data
Religious affiliation: Church in Wales
Day/boarding type: Day and Full Boarding
Gender profile: Boys and girls taught separately (diamond structure)
Size: 1236

Boys - age range & pupil numbers:
Day: 3 to 18 (522)
Boarding: 7 to 18 (150)
Sixth form: (156)

Girls - age range & pupil numbers:
Day: 3 to 18 (456)

Boarding: 7 to 18 (108)

Sixth form: (104)

Answer (score 0):

This example will give you a start how to select tags from the page and extract the required text:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/wales/monmouthshire/monmouth/haberdashers-monmouth-schools/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

aff = (
    soup.select_one('strong:-soup-contains("Religious affiliation")')
    .find_next_sibling(text=True)
    .strip()
)

boys = soup.select(".boys-range p:has(strong)")[1:]
boys = [p.get_text(strip=True).split(":") for p in boys]

girls = soup.select(".girls-range p:has(strong)")[1:]
girls = [p.get_text(strip=True).split(":") for p in girls]

print(aff)
print(boys)
print(girls)
```

Prints:

```
Church in Wales
[['Day', '3 to 18 (522)'], ['Boarding', '7 to 18 (150)'], ['Sixth form', ' (156)']]
[['Day', '3 to 18 (456)'], ['Boarding', '7 to 18 (108)'], ['Sixth form', ' (104)']]
```